# prompt error "localhost:8100 says gap_init:3" message while load ionic project in browser

Tags: android, ionic-framework

while i do changes in any page code there is a prompt message "localhost:8100 says  gap_init:3" shown. then I clicked 'ok' button another 5 messages shown. close browser and open it again work well. but do any changes it show this prompt. how to fix it?.
thanks in advance
[prompt error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ZOW.png)
console was be like that [console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ZOW.png)

[image]

[image: Console Error]

Comment: Are you opening an android project in the browser? You shouldnt do that, you should add browser module if you want to test on your browser you should add the browser module, using 'cordova platform add browser'
For local development check out: 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/serve/ 
Using ionic serve --lab launches a development server in your browser

Comment: thank you. "ionic serve --lab" working well. i used "ionic cordova run android -lc -- -d"

Answer (score 8):

After trying the above answers without success, I simply deleted the www folder and `ionic serve` again worked as expected

Comment: Was jumping between ionic versions, this solved issue while switching back to: 4.12.0 from 5.4.4.

Answer (score 3):

This error you get when you use the following command directly as follows:

```html
ionic serve
and then followed by 
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

I SUGGEST TO FOLLOW THIS METHOD, IF YOU WANT TO RUN THE APP IN BROWSER

```html
ionic serve
ionic build
ionic build --prod
```

This way you get www folder where you can upload to server and check the whole app in browser directly

Then follow to make the app ready for google play store

```html
ionic serve
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the `prompt` and you are on the go.

```
// include this before cordova.js

prompt = function() { return false; }
```

With that you could just ignore the prompted message because in the webview the `prompt` itself are disable.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I was using `ionic cordova run browser --livereload`. Try changing the simulator to an iPhone in Chrome. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I entered the following command in terminal continuously and directly in one time:

```
ionic serve ionic build ionic build --prod
```

Problem got away and `gap_init:3` didn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

**Delete the cordova.js from the www folder**

When I had this problem, I was playing around with different Ionic / Angular versions and their build tools. The problem for me boiled down to 2 different cordova.js files being included into the page. After quite some time I realized that I had an outdated cordova.js output file in my www folder. Clearing the whole folder solved the problem.